# Internet goes down when someone access our URL?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, internet, ethernet

Setup: Have a metal server in our office closet, host OS is windows 10. It hosts 4 VMs, one of which is an internet facing application and accessible via URL. The server has 2 network cards, the first which connects it to our office network, the second which is used by the aforementioned application VM with an external IP address pointing to our URL domain. The second network card connects directly to our Optimum Arris modem via ethernet.

The problem: There are two problems, but I do not know if they are related or not.

- First (minor) problem: The URL is not accessible when you are on the VPN or office network. Our URL, lets call app.myOffice.com for reference sake, is not accessible if a employee is on the VPN or connected directly to our office network.
- Second (major) problem: Whenever a outside non-VPN connection tries to access app.myOffice.com, the pings from the Server OS to 8.8.8.8 go from <20 ms to over 3000 ms to then timing out - I have tested this and it happens like clockwork. I can leave the ethernet in the second network card for hours without problem, but once someone outside (since you can't access it from inside the network now) tries to access app.myOffice.com, the pings start to time out and our whole office loses internet. Right now the solution is to unplug that wire, and internet comes back for everyone.

I'm relatively new to networking and am taking over while our normal IT person is on medical leave. I only just realized this data point about what is actually triggering the issue - accessing app.myOffice.com. I don't know where to go from here or how to try to fix this, or even what else to look at so any input as to what I can try to do is very much appreciated.

I can provide more details about our setup if asked.

Comment: Looks like your app is saturating your internet uplink, which then manifests in issue like this. You should have a separate internet connection for your app, or host the app in a service provider.